# Не правильно отправляю данные

Tags: ajax, javascript, post

Решил всё сам.

Comment: Интересно, вот от этого кода вы что ожидаете получить?

    if(dialogMessage.attr("value")){
        return true;        
       
        ....    
       
       // много всякого дркгого кода
    }

Comment: @rnddev, @DreamChild хотел сказать, что оператор return возвращает значение из функции и сразу прерывает ее дальнейшее выполнение.

Comment: >даже если убрать return ничего не меняется :(

@rnddev однако это не означает, что если написать подобную чепуху, то предыдущая ошибка исчезнет

Comment: на сервер вообще ничего не приходит? Что в консоле браузера пишет?

Comment: более того, что вы ожидаете получить от кода 

    if(dialogMessage.attr("value"))

где у вашей формы атрибут value?

Comment: > даже в консоле ничего нет :(

это хорошо. значит javascript-ошибки нет. 

> var dialogText         = $("#text");

Где у вас элемент, с id=text?

P.S.
Говорят, что за использование тега `<center>` скоро бить будут.

Comment: @rnddev, всё это выглядит очень печально. Хотите обижайтесь, но я с трудом понимаю, как можно что-либо писать, если не знаешь элементарных основ. Пусть не с JS в целом, но хоть с методами jQuery можно было познакомится поближе? Понять принцип работы, синтаксис и т.д. - это занимает не так много времени. По крайней мере, можно ведь держать открытым справочник перед глазами?

Comment: к содержимому textarea имеет смысл обращаться через val. Попробуйте вместо 
  
    if(dialogMessage.attr("value"))


написать 

    if(dialogMessage.val())

Comment: @DreamChild кроме того что станут отправляться пустые сообщения, это ничего не даст. Данные не отправляются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Уберите return true. //читаем про return
2. Атрибут задаёт значение при загрузке страницы. То, что хотите, это dialogMessage.val()
3. Не .attr('disabled','true'), а .prop('disabled', true) //читаем про атрибуты, свойства...

Comment: Если бы я хотел увидеть такой ответ, я мог создать вопрос на форуме, с грамотными пупами земли, которые могут только ссылку на криво написанный мануал дать, нежели дать дельный ответ.